# Refresh the page content automatically if questions are searched by a particular tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, updating-questions

When someone searches to answer some questions by a specific tag (say [java]), then currently Stack Overflow shows all the questions, which are related to that particular tag, which is good.

But after some time (say 5 minutes), if new questions are asked, then new questions are not refreshed. One has to manually refresh the page and get the newly asked questions.

Why not to refresh them continuously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, please don't.

I don't want content to be pushed on my screen without me asking for it.

There is already a "live refresh" feature that show a banner when new questions arrive, and let you click in order to load them:

> [image]

Comment: Aaah! this feature is even more beautiful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a little banner in place that shows the number of new questions in the search results. You can click on it to show all the most recently active questions.

[image]

Not everyone likes this, though. Many people (including me) sometimes want the page to automatically show questions with new activity. I propose to add a section to "Edit profile & settings" to chose if questions are automatically added to the screen or if it has to be manually refreshed.